# Collision Between tow entities

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine

i'm learning andengine . i'm creating a sample game . in this game there is a heliChopter , which can lunch mesile . there is a leaser gun which change its rotation according to the movement of helichopter . there is a missile lunch button . missile lunch button fire a missile . i want to detect the collision between leaser gun and mesile . but all i know the collision have to detect in the `onupdatemanaged()` function . I want to play some destruction animation like boomb !!! and play the sound of the destruction in this function. please give me some idea.

```
`private void addMesie(float x, final float f) {
    tempx = x;
    tempy = f;
 this.mesile = new AnimatedSprite(x, f, this.MesileTextureRegion,     this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
                        @Override
                        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

                                super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
                                this.setPosition(tempx , tempy);
                                if(laserCannon.collidesWith(this)){

                                }

                        }


                };
                this.mesile.animate(new long[]{100,100,100,100});
                this.mesile.setVisible(false);
                this.mScene.attachChild(mesile);

        }`
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle collision in onManageUpdate , instead try to use ContactListener to detect the collision of different object. Here you can easily play sound also.